# Is there a survey of recent work relating to the Hausdorff dimension of sets defined through some restriction of digits?

Tags: nt.number-theory, measure-theory, ergodic-theory, fractals, dimension-theory

I am familiar with the work of Helmut Cajar, but his book is thirty years old and it's clear that there has been substantial progress since then.  I have been spending a lot of time looking through mathscinet citations and am honestly a bit overwhelmed.  Also, I'm not just interested in sets defined through restrictions on digits of their decimals expansions, but also similar results pertaining to continued fraction expansion, Cantor series expansions, the Luroth series expansion, Engel series expansion, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess you'll find many recent pointers in the publication list of [Lars Olsen](https://risweb.st-andrews.ac.uk/portal/en/persons/lars-ole-ronnow-olsen(56a24580-14fb-4dc1-a075-8af7c42095a3)/researchoutput.html?pageSize=100&ordering=researchOutputOrderByPublicationYear&descending=true&page=0), and in that of [Godofredo Iommi](http://www.mat.puc.cl/~giommi/), for example:

- [Applications
  of multifractal divergence points to sets of numbers defined by their
  N-adic expansion](http://sci-prew.inf.ua/v136/1/S0305004103007047.pdf) (2004)
- [The frequency of
  digits in the Lüroth expansion](http://www.mat.puc.cl/~giommi/luroth_web.pdf) (2009)
- [Hausdorff Dimension of Cantor
  Series](http://arxiv.org/abs/0911.3876) (2009)